# React - Fire a function after user has selected a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What is the best way to fire a function **after** a user has selected a value.  For example, the user clicks rapidly to the number 10, stops, and then a function fires that contains that value.  Could be something like a console log.  Is a `debounce` the correct way to do this?  I'm having some trouble with the logic and some help would be greatly appreciated.

In my code below, I can get the `addToCart` function to fire only once after multiple clicks, which is what I want.  But the `amount` is stale. In the code you can see that there might be an occasion where `amount` changes, like when `cartAmount` has a value.  However, on the debounce, it only ever sees the value of `amount` as 1

Here is my code

```
const QuantitySelectorComponent = (props) => {
const {
    cartAmount,
} = props;

const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
    if (cartAmount) {
    setAmount(cartAmount); 
    }
}, [cartAmount]);

const increment = useMemo(() => debounce(() => {
    setAmount(amount => amount + 1);
    addToCart(amount)
}, 2000), [addToCart]);

const decrement = useMemo(() => debounce(() => {
    setAmount(amount => amount - 1);
    addToCart(amount)
}, 2000), [addToCart]);


return(
    <StyledQuantityWrapper>
        <StyledQuantityButton disabled={ amount <= 0 } 
            onClick={decrement} >
            &mdash;
        </StyledQuantityButton>
        <StyledQuantityInput onFocus={onFocus} onBlur={onBlur} className="quantity-input__screen" type="number" value={ amount } />
        <StyledQuantityButton disabled={ amount <= 0 } 
            onClick={increment} >
            &#xff0b;
        </StyledQuantityButton>
    </StyledQuantityWrapper>
)
```

}

export default QuantitySelectorComponent;

Comment: Do you mean when a user clicks 10 times rapidly then logs number 10 not 10 times? Like when a user clicks after a specific time then logs each click?

Comment: Sure, debouncing an "onChange" callback seems logical. If you are asking for "the best way to X" then I recommend rewording your question in order for it to be more objective (versus subjective, i.e. opinionated).

Comment: Click to a number, in this case, say 10. Then a function fires that does something with that number. I'm building a quantity selector that adds to cart after the user has finished selecting a number. Right now, it's firing with each click. That's too many calls. I want there to be one function that fires when the user is done selecting. I've never used debounce before, and I'm having some trouble with it

Comment: Can you share a code example *in your question* where you attempt to use a debouncing utility on a function call? There are libraries (i.e. lodash) that have a debounce function, or you could roll your own simple version.

Comment: hi, yes, sorry about that.  I've added my own code and tried to clarify the situation.  I'm using debounce from lodash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

The problem I see with your code is that you are debouncing the state update instead of debouncing the function you want to call after each state update.

## Suggestion

You want to debounce the `addToCart` function and allow all the normal React state updates to occur normally. In order to avoid any stale enclosures use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on the `amount` state to call the debounced version of `addToCart`.

Example

```
const QuantitySelectorComponent = (props) => {
  const firstRender = useRef(true);
  const { cartAmount } = props;

  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cartAmount) {
      setAmount(cartAmount);
    }
  }, [cartAmount]);

  const debouncedAddToCart = useMemo(() => debounce(addToCart, 2000), []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender.current) {
      // don't call addToCart on the initial render
      firstRender.current = false;
      return;
    }
    debouncedAddToCart(amount);
  }, [amount, debouncedAddToCart]);

  const increment = (value) => () => setAmount((c) => c + value);

  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={amount <= 0} onClick={increment(-1)}>
        &mdash;
      </button>
      <input
        onFocus={onFocus}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        className="quantity-input__screen"
        type="number"
        value={amount}
        onChange={e => setAmount(Number(e.target.value))}
      />
      <button disabled={amount < 0} onClick={increment(1)}>
        &#xff0b;
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-fire-a-function-after-user-has-selected-a-value]

Comment: oh, interesting!  However I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Expected a function` error

Comment: @DonegalBoyVancouver Where are you getting this error?

Comment: Hmm, it's in the component.  The console isn't being very helpful in telling me where though.  I thought it might be the `onClick` so I tried adding `onClick={() => {increment(-1)}} `, but no good.

Comment: @DonegalBoyVancouver Oh, I converted the increment/decrement into a single curried function, if that's tripping you up on anything. Is the error in my linked codesandbox? or elsewhere in your code? Can you share the full error?

Comment: sure.  I'm also getting this `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.`

Comment: Here is more of the `Expected a function` error:
at debounce (react_scripts.js?v=11474487036512061439:24608)
    at react_scripts.js?v=11474487036512061439:19643
    at mountMemo (react_scripts.js?v=11474487036512061439:31785)
    at Object.useMemo (react_scripts.js?v=11474487036512061439:31810)
    at useMemo (react_scripts.js?v=11474487036512061439:33751)

Comment: So when I comment out `debouncedAddToCart` and all references to it, it removes the error.  So the problem is in there somewhere

Comment: Oh, I think it's because `addToCart` requires the `amount` as a parameter.  In your code, I don't think you're doing that

Comment: @DonegalBoyVancouver Yeah, from the error it seems you've either not used the `useMemo` React hook correctly, or more likely you're not passing a function to `debounce`. Since you didn't include `addToCart` definition in your question I simply had to mock it. Can you update your question to include the `addToCart` definition so we've a better idea what you're working with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235502/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-donegalboyvancouver).

Answer (score 0):

you could use the useEffect hook to keep an eye on the change of the state count, and fire your function when count is 10.

```
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Counter() {
  // Set the initial count state to zero, 0
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (count === 10) {
      // fire your function
      console.log('--------', count);
    }
  }, [count]);

  // Create handleIncrement event handler
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem.  I'm trying to find a way to fire the function when the user finishes selecting any number. I just used 10 as an example.  I'm trying to build an add to cart application and when the user is done with their selection, the function takes that value and does something with it, like use that value as a quantity to add to the cart

Comment: Well, how do you get to know the use has select the last number and won't plus or minus any numbers? Maybe you could fire your function in other event functions eg. a user click and submit the cart order.

Comment: The answer involves using `debounce`.  But I'm having trouble getting it to work

Comment: The functionality is actually here. https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/great-outdoors?navid=flyout-L2-Camping%20Essentials

add an item to the cart and then modify the quantity.  You'll see that the add to cart only fires when the user is done selecting the quantity

Comment: I've updated the question and added my own code to clarify what I'm trying to do